# Python // Requests // ASP.net // No permission to access

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

im still learing at this. But first time I see, when I used requests module in Python, website give me feedback that I have no permission to access.
My code should only get data from site, and that's all.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_siemens_part = "https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/5SY6310-7"

with requests.session() as sr:
    partUrl = sr.get(url_siemens_part)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(partUrl.content,'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

Answer I get from this:

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/5SY6310-7" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.36d61202.1596089808.1cc0ef55
</p></body>
</html>
```

Website is using ASP.net. Site from chromebrowser is visible, but from requests is not.

Can you maybe give me show a way? It's problem with authentication? Maybe .ASPXAUTH or ASP.NET_SessionId I had to use?

Thanks in advance for your time, and any anwsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom `User-Agent` HTTP header to obtain correct response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_siemens_part = "https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/5SY6310-7"

with requests.session() as sr:
    sr.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'})
    partUrl = sr.get(url_siemens_part)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(partUrl.content,'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=10" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>


... and so on.
```

Comment: oh god : o  it's working. But question now. This headers update when i run script, tells to server we are "a browser" not a script? I understand well?

Comment: @ArturY Yes, it sends to server `User-Agent` equal to standard browser. Some sites have protections to not send response to bots etc...

Comment: Thank You rly for help :)  now I can read more about this and try more and more :) Have a nice day!

Comment: So maybe one more question to You, maybe you have some ebooks or docs, which can help with trying to log into website with ASP.net and SSH. Because some data are behind the login and thinking about what information should be send in "POST" to site with this ASP.net.  It's more problematic than get phpsession_id. I see information in request / response cookie. Some authorization etc. Im trying read everything i can to understand how its work : o :)

Comment: @ArturY getting information/logi to ASP.net sites are always tricky. You can open Firefox (Chrome) Developer Tools -> Network tab and observe what information is sent to server upon login. But there is always problems with cookies, custom http headers...

Comment: Yes, I know it and observe. Oh i found now Formdata, when I clicked button "Log in" then script was loaded and next step was reload site... first time i didn't saw this, and now i have form data to try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it . If you don't have the lib, You can install first. `pip install requests-html`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
url_siemens_part = "https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/5SY6310-7"
sr = HTMLSession()
partUrl = sr.get(url_siemens_part)
soup = BeautifulSoup(partUrl.content,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0):

With login is all good :) can download all data, but its a problem when I have something like below.

```
price_catalog = soup.find_all("td",class_="priceDetailsListPrice")
```

After soup need to find some values, writing as find_all "td"

I get output:

```
[<td class="priceDetailsListPrice">244,86 EUR
</td>]
```

its some other way than write "for" function like:

```
for price_catalog in price_catalog:
    output = price_catalog.text
```

I think its too much to use "for" for single value :(